# Beaglebone Black not booting due to modification of uEnv.txt

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I accidently modified uEnv.txt file located in eMMC of my Beaglebone black. Now the board is not booting. I can not even see BBB for serial connection from terra term. How can I get access to the board? If I can just access to uboot I could reflash or run it using nfs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can boot via normal microSD card as described [here](http://beagleboard.org/getting-started):

1. burn a bootable image on your microSD card
2. insert this card
3. power up your BBB while holding USER/BOOT button
4. once in Linux - repair your uEnv.txt on eMMC

Comment: I didn't find "repair your uEnv.txt on eMMC" intuitively obvious.  Here are the commands that worked for me:  sudo su; mkdir /mnt/disk; mount /dev/mmcblk1p2 disk; cp -p /boot/uEnv.txt /mnt/disk/boot/uEnv.txt